# Javascript regex to validate a decimal before inserting into MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, regex

I have a regex to validate a decimal value before inserting into MySql database, but there is an issue with it. It is allowing a just the negative symbol with no digits after it.

So for example, I'm validating against a decimal(7,2).
Here is my regex:

```
^[+-]?\d{0,5}(?:\.\d{0,2})?$
```

And here are the valid/invalid values

```
Valid
-1
+1 
1
+.1
-.1 
.1
+11111.11
-11111.11
11.11 
11111
+1.
-1.
1.

Invalid 
1111111
11.11111
0.111111 
.1111111
+111111.11
-111111.11
+11111.111
-11111.111
11111.111
111111.11
-
+
```

The problem is that it shows - and + as valid. How can I get these values to be invalid?

Comment: Is it on purpose that you have sometimes 2 numbers on the same line separated by a space? Is there some meaning to that?

Comment: why `'-.1 .1'` should be valid?

Comment: Those were copy/paste errors. I edited the post.

Comment: Could you "correct" the input by simply using `if (input === "-") {input = "0"};`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if there's at least one digit at position 0 or 1 or 2 with a lookahead:

```
^(?=.{0,2}\d)[+-]?\d{0,5}(?:\.\d{0,2})?$
```

or use an alternation as in @trincot answer.

Comment: Nice. `^(?=.*?\d)[+-]?\d{0,5}(?:\.\d{0,2})?$`  works good too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use alternatives:

- One that requires at least one digit in the integral part of the number with optional decimals
- One that matches a number that does not have digits in the integral part and has decimal(s)

```
^[-+]?(?:\d{1,5}(?:\.\d{0,2})?|\.\d{1,2})$
```

Answer (score 0):

The "valid values" list shows that you want to match both integer and float numbers with size constraint. The following should work:

```
^[+-]?(\d{1,5}|\d{0,5}\.\d{0,2})$
```

https://regex101.com/r/NdmIWo/1